# Installing Win32::Unicode::Console fails on Windows 10: Failed test at t/04_print.t

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to install [Win32::Unicode::Console](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode::Console) on Windows 10. I am using Strawberry Perl. From the command prompt:

```
> perl --version
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 1 (v5.30.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
> chcp
Active code page: 65001
> perl Makefile.PL
Writing ppport.h
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Win32::Unicode
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
> gmake
[...]
> gmake test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Unicode.bs blib\arch\auto\Win32\Unicode\Unicode.bs 644
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00_compile.t ........... ok
t/01_load.t .............. ok
t/02_export.t ............ ok
t/03_encode.t ............ ok
t/04_print.t ............. 1/?
#   Failed test at t/04_print.t line 14.
# STDOUT is:
#  I â¥ Perl
# not:
#  I ♥ Perl
# as expected

#   Failed test at t/04_print.t line 15.
# STDOUT is:
# [ I â¥ Perl]
# not:
# [ I ♥ Perl]
# as expected

#   Failed test at t/04_print.t line 16.
# STDOUT is:
#  I â¥ Perl
#
# not:
#  I ♥ Perl
#
# as expected
t/04_print.t ............. 5/? # Looks like you failed 3 tests of 13.
t/04_print.t ............. Dubious, test returned 3 (wstat 768, 0x300)
Failed 3/13 subtests
t/05_write.t ............. ok
t/06_dir_functions.t ..... ok
t/06_dir_methods.t ....... ok
t/06_dir_tree.t .......... ok
t/07_file.t .............. ok
t/08_error.t ............. ok
t/09_normalize.t ......... ok
t/10_read.t .............. ok
t/10_read_with_offset.t .. ok
t/11_write.t ............. ok
t/12_syswrite.t .......... ok
t/13_system.t ............ ok
t/15_flock.t ............. ok
t/15_flock_win32.t ....... ok
t/16_io_handle_like.t .... ok
t/17_slurp.t ............. ok
t/30_native.t ............ ok
t/31_native_import.t ..... ok
t/32_native_file.t ....... ok
t/33_native_dir.t ........ ok
t/34_args.t .............. ok
t/50_util.t .............. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_print.t           (Wstat: 768 Tests: 13 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Non-zero exit status: 3
Files=27, Tests=284, 25 wallclock secs ( 0.16 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/27 test programs. 3/284 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:1038: test_dynamic] Error 255
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://github.com/xaicron/p5-win32-unicode/issues/7 . Even on cpan tester it is failing for all different versions on windows - http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Win32-Unicode+0.38

Comment: Not able to understand properly because of the language barrier but looks like there is already a pull request waiting for merge - https://github.com/xaicron/p5-win32-unicode/pull/8